# Can't reference a method property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods, properties, polymorphism

I'm trying to call a function

```
NextPrevious((List<Store>)model.Group.ToList(), 3, groupPage.Value, ref next, ref previous);
```

With the method definition being..

```
private void NextPrevious(List<Store> model, int numFields, int page, ref bool nextRef, ref bool previousRef)
{
    ...
}
```

But I get a cannot convert Group to Store error.
model is a variable from a class which contains a list of Group objects and some more.

Group is also a subclass of the class Store.

I'm only checking basic `List<>` stuff inside the method, like `method.Count` or `method.Skip()` so if there's some easier way to do this, I'm all ears, I'm not calling any of the specific Store or Group methods.

Sorry if I posted too little information, I can post more if needed. Thanks!

Comment: what is the actual value of model.Group.ToList()? can you post it?

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<Group>` is not a `List<Store>`. However, you can use a type argument to the `ToList` method to make it create a `List<Store>` instead:

```
NextPrevious(model.Group.ToList<Store>(), ...)
```

That's assuming you're using C# 4 or higher and .NET 4 or higher, so you can use the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign generic collections with different types to each other! `List<Class> = List<Subclass>` because those collections are not of same type!

If You are 100% sure that model.Group contains only elements of type Store you can do this one `model.Group.Select(x => (Store)x).ToList()` or `model.Group.OfType<Store>().ToList()`

If You are not sure `model.Group.Where(x => x is Store).Select(x => (Store)x).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Make your `List<Store>` an `IEnumerable<Store>`.

The reason why your `List<StoreDerivedClass>` is *not* a `List<Store>`, but your `IEnumerable<StoreDerivedClass>` *is* an `IEnumerable<Store>` is [Co- and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).